# Basic Java - How to use methods and such

Tags: java, class, methods, point

My task is to write a class called Point, which has two data members of type double. Default constructor should initialize point to origin. Also create an overloaded constructor fot the Point class which takes two doubles as parameters. This class should have methods getX, getY, setX, setY, and setXY in order to get and set data members. Also include toString method for this class that outputs coordinates for this point.

This is what my code looks like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Point {

private double x;
private double y;

public void getX(){
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      double x = scan.nextInt();
}
public double setX(double x){
    return x;
}
public void getY(){
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      double y = scan.nextInt();
}
public double sety(double y){
    return y;
}
public void setXY(double x, double y){
    double xy = (x + y);
}
public String toString(double xy){
    return xy;
}

}
```

Can someone assist me in telling me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: where is overloaded constructor? It is missing. also toString() seems to be returnign xy, but I dont' see it defined. Define a string private String xy; and then you don't need to pass any parameters to toString() just have public String toString() { return "x: " + x + " " + "y: " + y; }

Comment: One thing you are doing wrong is, you are trying to write code without understanding what the code is supposed to do.  What do you think a method named `setXY(double x, double y)` is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Point` will be used in other code e.g. a runnable class with a `main` method.

From this other code your will instantiate a `Point` Object i.e. by using the `Contructor`

e.g.

```
Point myPoint = new Point (1.23, 3.45);
```

See how the constructor is being passed the data.
Your `Point` class then should have a constructor like

```
public Point (double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

If you use an IDE like Eclipse and declare fields such as

```
 double x;
 double y;
```

then it is simply a case on right clicking on the field to automatically generate `setters` and `getters` and they will look like

```
public void setX (double x) {
  this.x = x;
}
```

The idea of this type of class is to hold data.  As the data i.e. `x` and `y` is being already held, then it is not necessary to pass this data into the class again to simply print it out, thus

```
public String toString(){
  return "x:" + x + " y:" + y);
}
```

Based on the above, I am sure you can figure out the `setXY` method.